# Is it possible to queue up app submissions to the Office Addin Store?

Tags: office-store

Our team would like to schedule the release of our Office add-in, but it looks like once the submission is approved, it is automatically uploaded to the store as the latest version.

Is it possible to indicate a schedule, or at least put the submission in queue, after it has been approved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem but about the internal workings of the office-store.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to indicate a start date while uploading your latest submission via Seller Dashboard. This means that once your submission is approved it will be hidden in the Store until that date.
 **Please note that doing this for an update to an existing submission will also hide the live version of your app or add-in until the date specified.**

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Thanks!